# Disable virtual_localdelivery in exim (local mail delivery using directadmin)

Tags: email, exim, directadmin

when sending two test e-mails (1 has account on our server, number 2, the other does not)

Now when testing I see that email number 1 is being sent locally using virtual_localdelivery and not routed via the MX servers (we use Google apps, so that is where I am expecting the email)

The other email 2, using different email is correctly deliverd using MX records to Google app

**Question:** how do I setup exim to follow the MX records for ALL emails?

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uncheck **Local Mail Server** options for that domain.

```
Go to User Panel -> domain.com -> MX Records

There should be an option for "Local Mail Server".   Uncheck that option.
```